# Javascript array and objects program is not executing? The console on Google developer tools is showing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' { '

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, developer-tools

> **I am getting an error as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'**

**Here is the Javascript code that I have written**-

```
var database=
[
 {
    username:"Kevin",
    password:"Robotboy"
 }
];

var newsFeed=
[
 {
    username:"David",
    timeline:"It's an eye opening thought!"
 },

 {
    username:"Kane",
    timeline:"What a wonderful day!"
 }
];

var userNamePrompt=prompt("What is your username?");
var passwordPrompt=prompt("What is your password?");

function signIn(user,pass)
{
    if(user===database[0].username && pass===database[0].password)
    {
        console.log(newsFeed);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("ERR, no such account exists!");
    }
}
```

**And here is the HTML code**-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Coding\Html\Learn\newweb\newjavascript\December19\socialsite.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know why the situation is arising?

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine (if you call `signIn()`)

Comment: Can you add which line GDT spotted this error?

Comment: Please do not perform authentication on the client side.

Comment: @NickParsons problem solved! Thanks for your time!

Comment: @KarulessWhisper problem is solved, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Terry the issue os solved. But please elaborate what do you mean by 'not performing authentication on the client-side'.